# Cant create a database android

Tags: java, android, sql

I have created a DatabaseHandler class extended from SQLiteOpenHelper . I have used the same class in another project and it worked perfectly , but when I imported it in the directory of my current project it doesn't work properly . It doesn't even create a database . Here are the methods which creates the database and the tables .

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_WORDS = "words";
private static final String TABLE_SETS = "sets";
// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_WORD = "word";
private static final String KEY_DEFINITION = "definition";
private static final String KEY_WORDS_SET_ID = "wordssetid";

private static final String KEY_SET_NAME = "setname";
private static final String KEY_SET_ID = "setid";



public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createWordTable = 
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_WORDS+ "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_WORD + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DEFINITION + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_WORDS_SET_ID+" INTEGER) ";
    String createSetTable = 
            "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_SETS+"("
            +KEY_SET_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
            +KEY_SET_NAME+ " TEXT) ";
    db.execSQL(createWordTable );
    db.execSQL(createSetTable);
    db.close();
}
```

Creating and using the object in the Activity class

```
private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_sets);
    //...
    //...
            //...
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler (this);

}
```

I have done the same thing in the other project , but now it doest work . What is the reason ?

Comment: Any Errors in the Logcat??

Comment: No , simply it doesn't work

Comment: Have you used dbHandler to run a query? The database won't be created until you do. Set a breakpoint in onCreate() and onUpgrade() and debug, or write to the log from within those methods to see what code is being run.

Comment: if `DatabaseHandler` is  subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` than delete `db.close();` from `onCreate`

Comment: @Selvin nothing changed , unfortunately

Comment: @NigelK , what query to write if there is not a database created ?

Comment: onCreate() is not called until you do getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase. I assume your helper makes such calls when you run a query, so when you first try to use the database it'll get created at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    onCreate(db);
}
```

if it is not work:

create this method on your DatabaseHandler class

```
public void createDB()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    onCreate(db);
}
```

And in your Activity class

```
DatabaseHandler dbHandler=new DatabseHandler(this);
dbHandler.createDB();
```

Comment: The problem is already solved , but however thank you for reply